# Do CSS media queries have to be in an external CSS file?

Tags: ios, css, media-queries

I've seen similar questions, but not this exactly.

Do CSS media queries have to be in an external CSS file to work properly?

I've got a client who I’ve only got access to an inline css block within WordPress. Their IT department has the CMS really locked down, and the only thing I have access to change is the CSS via a plugin called Improved Simpler CSS that puts an inline block of `<style type="text/css"></style>` before the `<head>` closes.

In doing the site, the browser seems to pick up the "inline" media queries OK, responding to changing the browser's width, but utilizing an iPhone or iOS simulator, I only get the desktop view, and I'm thinking iOS doesn't like the CSS not being externalized.

```
<style type="text/css">
/* Mobile-specific media query */
@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width:767px) {

  #wrapper,
  .home #content,
  .page #container,
  .page .page, 
  #footer,
  .page #content {
    width: 100%;
  }

  #header {
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    width: 95%;
    width: -moz-calc(100% - 20px);
    width: -webkit-calc(100% - 20px);
    width: calc(100% - 20px);
    height: 151px;
  }
}
</style>
```

Comment: What you have should work, so I think it's a matter of not including the viewport meta tag I suggested in my answer. If you have access to the `head`, try adding it.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't. Totally locked down.

Comment: Won't work unless you have the viewport meta tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Media queries are perfectly valid within `<style>`, they don't have to be within an external stylesheet.

Make sure you include the viewport meta tag in your head (if you haven't already):

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

It would also help if you include the CSS you currently have.

Comment: Unfortunately, the viewport tag is not in the code/theme and all I've got access to is the CSS. I'm unable to add anything to the PHP/Markup, add JS, etc. I'm really limited.

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to load the CSS on a local instance/install (where it's not locked down), add the viewport and confirm that's the issue.

Comment: Pulled down a copy from the client's server (as close as a copy as I could easily via WordPress' export). Added the viewport meta tag, and the media queries work. Remove it, and they do not.

Answer (score 4):

No, they don't have to be external...

[**MDN's docs on Media Queries**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) demonstrates the two main ways of setting media queries:

```
<!-- CSS media query on a link element -->
<link rel="stylesheet" media="(max-width: 800px)" href="example.css" />

<!-- CSS media query within a stylesheet -->
<style>
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .facet_sidebar {
    display: none;
  }
}
</style>
```

Comment: I'm doing the latter.